# Parse and split a hexadecimal bytearray in python

Tags: python, string, split, hex

I would like to parse and split a hexadecimal bytearray read from the vehicle CAN. The entire 64 bits were read as `bytearray(b'\xa0\xc6\xa6\xc2\x06\xe3)B')`, and I would like to split it based on bit positions. For example, I need the first 6 bits of `101000`.

Based on some reading from here, I've completed the conversion from hex bytearray to binary string, and parse it successfully. My current approach is:

```
orig_data = bytearray(b'\xa0\xc6\xa6\xc2\x06\xe3)B')

def hex2bin(hex_string):
    scale = 16  
    num_of_bits = 8
    return bin(int(hex_string, scale))[2:].zfill(num_of_bits)

bin_str = hex2bin(bytes(orig_data).hex())

print(bin_str[:6])
```

Since I need to deal with a vast amount of data transferring at high speed, I was wondering if there is a faster way to do that than the current approach I adopted?

Comment: once you've parsed the data to an int, you can do your bit operations on the data.  That should be faster than manipulating a string.

Comment: or actually just use the bytearray.

Comment: @monkut Thanks, I figured out. `bin(orig_data[0])[2:8]` should do the work.